# Check if viewport zoomed

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, viewport, mobile-chrome

Is there an easy way to check whether the user scaled the page (using pinch on mobile devices)?

Thought [verge.js](http://verge.airve.com/) would help, but I don't know what I can compare `viewportH` with.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the screen.width to the window.innerWidth. If the value is anything other than 1, the viewport has been zoomed.

```
viewportScale = screen.width / window.innerWidth;
alert(viewportScale);
```

References:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.screen

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.innerWidth

Comment: Does `screen.width` exclude the (possible) vertical scrollbar width as `innerWidth` does?

Comment: Check this link on your mobile browser and see if you find something useful:
http://www.quirksmode.org/m/tests/metadynamic.html

Some other really good resources to try and find what you are looking for:
http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/

Comment: Doesn't work anymore. Tested on iPhone 7 + and it was 1 in vertical, but in horizontal mode screen.width was 414 when window.innerWidth was 736. Worked fine on Chrome for Android on Note 4, though, for both orientations.

Answer (score 1):

```
    (
        document.documentElement.clientWidth
    /   window.innerWidth
    )
>
    1
```

Only for mobile devices, though!