# Is there a way to detect if an iPhone user is using Display Zoom View "Zoomed"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, mobile-safari

I'm trying to update my webpage so it will look good if mobile iPhone users have set the Display Zoom View to Zoomed (Settings > Display & Brightness > Display Zoom > Zoomed).

Is there a way to detect if a user is using the Zoomed Display so I can resize some of the text/images/buttons so they fit nicely on the screen?

Comment: You might be able to do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19888098/check-if-viewport-zoomed but that's only a guess

Comment: That doesn't seem to be reliable, but thank you